# Add transitional pages to pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I need to add pagination to transient pages now when a have 9 pages it looks like this:
1 2 3 ... 9

I would like to give a middle point between 3 and 9, i.e.

1 2 3 ... 6 ... 9

I also want the same middle subpage to be when I'm on the last / middle page. But this should be done by yourself knowing how to take the first step.

All my ideas fail. Does anyone have an idea for such a solution?

Full working code here:

```
<?php

 
 if( is_singular() )
     return;

 global $wp_query;

 /** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
 if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
     return;

 $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
 $max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

 /** Add current page to the array */
 if ( $paged >= 1 )
     $links[] = $paged;

 /** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
 if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
     $links[] = $paged - 1;
     $links[] = $paged - 2;
 }

 if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
     $links[] = $paged + 2;
     $links[] = $paged + 1;
 }

 echo '<div class="navigation"><ul>' . "\n";

 /** Previous Post Link */
 if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
     printf( '<li class="prev_post">%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link('<') );

 /** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
 if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
     $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';

     printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

     if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
         echo '<li>…</li>';
 }

 /** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
 sort( $links );
 foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
     $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
     printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
 }

 /** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
 if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
     if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
         echo '<li >…</li>' . "\n";

     $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
     printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
 }

 /** Next Post Link */
 if ( get_next_posts_link() )
     printf( '<li class="next_post">%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link('>') );

 echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general pagination codeflow might look like the following:

```php
<?php

function getPageDisplayArray(int $currentPage, int $totalCount, int $pageLen = 10): array
{
   $paginationArr[$currentPage] = 1;
   $totalPagesToDisplay = floor(($totalCount) / $pageLen);
   
   //Get preceding pages logic
   $pagesBefore = $currentPage - 1;
   $iBefore = 2; //Number of pages you want befpre the current page
   while($pagesBefore > 0 && $iBefore > 0) { 
       $paginationArr[$pagesBefore--] = 0;
       $iBefore--;
   }

   //Get anteceding pages
   $pagesAfter = $totalPagesToDisplay - ($pagesBefore + 1);
   $iAfter = min([$pagesAfter, 2]); //Number of pages you want after your current page
   while(-$iAfter < 0) { 
       //Either return the two pages after or don't if there are no pages after
       $paginationArr[$iAfter + $currentPage] = 0;
       $iAfter--;
   }

   if($pagesAfter > 2) {
       //Calcluate Midpoint
       $midpoint = floor($totalPagesToDisplay / 2) + 1;
       if(!isset($paginationArr[$midpoint])) {
           $paginationArr[$midpoint] = 0;
       }
   }
   //Link the first page always if it hasn't already been set
   if(!isset($paginationArr[1])) {
       $paginationArr[1] = 0;
   }

   //Link the final page if it has not already been set.
   if(!isset($paginationArr[$totalPagesToDisplay])) {
      $paginationArr[$totalPagesToDisplay] = 0;
   }
   ksort($paginationArr);
   return $paginationArr;
}
```

Where the Current Page, page length, and Total count are your parameters. The here will show two pages on either side as Display pages, as well as the first, last, and middle pages of your set for any arbitrart set. This will return a config array which sets the "Active" page with a value of one, and all of the others with a key of their page number and a value of zero. The rest would be a matter of displaying the values in your layout as you see fit.